# Dell laptop got memory error when bringing around

Tags: windows-10, memory, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude 7480 running on Windows 10 with 2x8GB RAM.

When I work in the office, the laptop runs normally, but when I put it into my backpack and bring it home. I cannot start the laptop or it gets this after a few minutes.
[image]

It needs to hard reset to start the laptop. The diagnostics LEDs display 2 amber lights and 4 white lights. I did Google it and they say it is Memory/RAM failure.

It kind of weird because it will work normally if I don't move the laptop, even I run the diagnostic test on SupportAssist from Dell, it passed all the test.

How can I solve this problem? Should I replace the RAM and how can I know which one has the problem?

**Update:**

After testing by using each memory slot at a time, I found that my memory card works fine, the problem is the memory slot on the left have a problem. It makes my laptop cannot start.

Comment: If you bring it back to work, does it work again? Have you verified that the RAM sticks are well seated?

Comment: @harrymc If I bring it back to work, it happens again, I have to hard reset the laptop to make it start. I did uninstall and reinstall the RAMs. I also run the diagnostic test on SupportAssist with each RAM and it passed all.

Comment: Problems that happen after transporting are logically related to loose connections. If you suspect RAM problem, run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours, at least overnight. If nothing is found, perhaps a repair-shop will help.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your help. I will check it.

Comment: @harrymc I've just updated my situation. Do you think I should replace my motherboard?

Comment: It's maybe just a question of a loose connection that a professional repairman can easily fix, before investing in a new motherboard.